# Why twig negative (not) conditional works like this?

Tags: symfony, twig

I don't understand why Twig `not` is working like this :

```
{{ dump( false ) }}
{{ dump( not(false) ) }}

{{ dump ( date1.timestamp > date2.timestamp ) }}
{{ dump ( not(date1.timestamp > date2.timestamp) ) }}

{% set comp = date1.timestamp > date2.timestamp %}
{{ dump ( comp ) }}
{{ dump ( not(comp) ) }}
```

Result :

```
false
true

false
false

false
true
```

Thank's for your help :)

Comment: Can reproduce  @DarkBee : https://twigfiddle.com/udjjti/2

Comment: Seems to be a bug in `twig 3.X` though, works fine in `twig 2.X` - But seems you've already opened a ticket on gitgub for it :)

Comment: Yes ! Thank you :)